# How to get sum / total length of lines per polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, grouping

I have a line vector layer which has multiple segments within individual polygons in a separate polygon layer. I have spatially joined the attributes so that each line segment now has the same ID as its corresponding polygon.

I need to calculate the lengths of the lines within each polygon according to the polygon ID. Is there an expression I can use to do this? I have already calculated the lengths of the individual segments but I need to get the sum of these according to each unique polygon ID.

I am a novice at complex SQL expressions within QGIS, ideally I would like a new column displaying the info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the **Sum Line Lengths** tool from the toolbar:

*Vector > Analysis Tools > Sum Line Lengths*

You will receive a polygon output with the sum of all lines within each polygon.

---

Alternatively, you could use the **GroupStats** plugin (which you can download/install from *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*). I wrote a somewhat similar answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160379/way-to-find-minimum-value-from-a-group-of-values-qgis) where you could change the options to find the sum of each ID. However, this will only display the results (which you could copy to a text editor or csv file). You would have to manually input the results using the **Field Calculator** to your layer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Joseph, worked perfectly!

Comment: @Ian - Most welcome buddy! Glad it worked for you :)